# Problem with proof of the Prime Number Theorem in Nathanson's book

Tags: number-theory

In Melvyn Nathanson's "Elementary Methods in Number Theory", on page 311 we find each $\big(x/\rho^j,x/\rho^{j-1}\big]$ contains a subinterval $I_{j}=\big(y_{j},e^{\delta'_m/2}y_{j}\big]$ s.t. $|R(t)|<4\delta'_mt=\delta_mt/2\ \ \forall t\in I_{j}$, using lemma 9.3. We then apply this to

$\displaystyle{\sum_{n\in(\rho^{j-1},\rho^j]}{\bigg|R\bigg(\frac{x}{n}\bigg)\bigg|}=\sum_{n\in(\rho^{j-1},\rho^j]\setminus I_j}{\bigg|R\bigg(\frac{x}{n}\bigg)\bigg|}+\sum_{n\in I_{j}}{\bigg|R\bigg(\frac{x}{n}\bigg)\bigg|}}\ .$

I could be wrong but I don't think $(\rho^{j-1},\rho^j]\setminus I_j$ is correct because $I_{j}$ is a subset of $\big(x/\rho^j,x/\rho^{j-1}\big]$ but not necessarily a subset of $\left(\rho^{j-1},\rho^j\right]$.

Further down the page we have $\displaystyle{\sum_{n\in I_{j}}{\bigg|R\bigg(\frac{x}{n}\bigg)\bigg|}<\frac{\delta_mx}{2}\sum_{n\in I_j}\frac{1}{n}}$, using the inequality established just before, but we can only do this for $\displaystyle{\frac{x}{n}\in I_j}$.

Am I correct in that this is an issue and, if so, has anyone found a workaround? Many thanks.

Comment: I can't help because your question is not self-contained. Explain what you proved and what this step is useful for in the PNT.

Comment: same, as (i imagine most) people don't have that particular book, we can't really help unless all details are given. For instance, we have no idea what $\rho$ is, nor many of the other characters

Comment: Well after looking at the [book](https://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/NEW/Math/MT_Number%20theory/Nathanson%20M.B.%20Elementary%20Methods%20in%20Number%20Theory%20(GTM,%20Springer,2000)(ISBN%200387989129)(518s)_MT_.pdf) $R(x) = \vartheta(x)-x, \vartheta(x) = \sum_{p \le x} \log p$. That's the kind of things you **need** to mention.

Comment: I think you're right: the author probably should have introduced something like $N_j=\{n: x/n\in I_j\}$, and write $(\rho^{j-1},\rho^j]\setminus N_j$ instead of $(\rho^{j-1},\rho^j]\setminus I_j$. Then, it _might_ make some sense.

Comment: And the chapter is about the elementary proof of the PNT. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/259719/84768) for an explanation of how it works. @ProfessorVector